# Обнаружение скрытых пакетов

Tags: linux, windows

есть ли действенные способы обнаружить порт и трафик если они скрыты?

Comment: Что такое "скрыты" применительно к linux?

Comment: вообщем раб. стол снимается, пакеты Wireshark не обнаруживает и портов нету открытых, вот собственно и вопрос как это чудо обнаружить.

Comment: Что такое "раб. стол снимается", опять же применительно к linux?

Comment: удаленное подключение к раб. столу без управления.